# Вопрос по синтаксису использования make_uniuque

Tags: c++, c++11

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как синтаксически верно переделать эту строчку:

```
m_instance.reset(new T(std::forward < Args > (args) ...));
```

с использованием `std::make_unique`? Как ни пробовал - пишет, что не может сопоставить аргумент шаблона для `_Ty`, не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция и т.п.

```
template < typename ... Args >
static void construct(Args && ... args)
{
    m_instance.reset(new T(std::forward < Args > (args) ...));
}
```

Это общий вид статической функции шаблонного класса. `m_instance` - это `static std::unique_ptr < T >`. Хочу убрать `new` и задать `m_instance` через `make_uniuque`, как-то так: `m_instance(std::make_unique( /* а тут что ? */ ))`. Как писать `...` для `std::make_unique`?

Comment: покажите минимальный пример того, что Вы делаете, что бы другие могли попробовать это скомпилировать и то, как Вы хотите, чтобы оно выглядело.

Comment: @KoVadim добавил

Comment: Приведите ваш вариант использования `std::make_unique` и полный текст ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что Вы пробовали, прежде чем задать вопрос? Ответ ведь прост:

```
m_instance = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward < Args > (args) ...);
```

Comment: Да, именно так уже и сделал, спасибо. Проблема была в том, что я не указал <T> для make_unique.